# Android monitor.bat does not see processes on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, galaxy, ddms

I am developing against an Samsung Galaxy S3 that this connected by a USB cable to my Windows 7 laptop.

I have installed the most recent version of Samsung Kies and the USB drivers are present. The phone has debugging turned on and is visible to adb.

Android's monitor.bat (was called DDMS) shows the phone and the logcat but not the processes.

- How do I get Monitor.bat to see the Galaxy S3's processes?

Comment: It should only see debuggable processes, not all processes. This is standard for production devices.